# How to adjust width of combo box popup in UWP App

Tags: win-universal-app, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am using combo box and want to adjust the width of popup(Drop Down) of a combo box. i am using xaml & C#.

Comment: Where is your code? How can anyone answer this without seeing any code?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably bind the popup's Width property to the combobox's "ActualWidth" property.

but if you want to write a code for it it's also possible, do something like this:

```
TestPopUp.Width = TestComboBox.ActualWidth;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new style for the combobox and apply it.  You can find the default template for UWP combo boxes here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299116.aspx

In particular, look at adjusting this element in the style
    `<Popup x:Name="Popup">`

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
       ...
       <Popup x:Name="Popup" Width="300">
       ...
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox Style={StaticResource MyComboBoxStyle} />
```

Comment: I agree of the part modifying the template style of the combobox, but why put the style in the resource of an UserControl? Are you suggestion that OP need to create a `UserControl` to modify the style and make the `ComboBox` become a new control?